# Rendering a PDF with emojis using PrintedPdfDocument

Tags: java, android, pdf, emoji

I'm using Android's built-in [PrintedPdfDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/pdf/PrintedPdfDocument) to draw PDFs with a Canvas as outlined in [this](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs#draw-content) document's example code:

```
private void drawPage(PdfDocument.Page page) {
  Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

  // units are in points (1/72 of an inch)
  int titleBaseLine = 72;
  int leftMargin = 54;

  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  paint.setTextSize(36);
  canvas.drawText("Test Title", leftMargin, titleBaseLine, paint);

  paint.setTextSize(11);
  canvas.drawText("Test paragraph", leftMargin, titleBaseLine + 25, paint);

  paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
  canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 172, 172, paint);
}
```

Is it possible to add emoji text to this document?  I cannot figure out how to set character sets/encodings.

Whenever I try adding emoji output it shows up garbled in the pdf.

This is the code which saves the pdf:

```
mPdfDocument = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, printAttributes);
mCurrentPage = mPdfDocument.startPage(1);
Canvas canvas = mCurrentPage.getCanvas();
... // add stuff to canvas
mPdfDocument.finishPage(mCurrentPage);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
mPdfDocument.writeTo(fos);
fos.close();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.  Here is some sample code:

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSansEmoji.ttf");
paint.setTypeface(typeface);
```

You can find the OpenSansEmoji.ttf typeface [here](https://github.com/MorbZ/OpenSansEmoji/blob/master/OpenSansEmoji.ttf) or find some other emoji font.

Place this file in your assets/fonts folder in your Android project.

Answer (score 0):

Create a string with the unicode value of the emoji. Then pass the string to drawText method:

`String smileyFace = new String(Character.toChars(0x1F603))); //0x1F603 = Smile emoji
canvas.drawText(smileyFace, leftMargin, titleBaseLine, paint);`

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work.  It still shows up garbled on the final PDF.  Edited my original question to show sample code which generates the PDF after adding stuff to the canvas.